# is there in JavaSE a similar class to Android's LocationManager

Tags: java, android, geolocation, locationmanager

I am developing 2 apps:

One in android and the other one in Java SE.

The android app sends GPS location to a MYSQL database, and the javaSE app has to get that data from the DB to show it to the desktop user. The problem is I can't find any javaSE class similar to those used in android (LocationManager, LocationProvider, Location...), so I do not know how to engage this proyect. any advice on this?

And by the way, does anybody know if googleMaps api can be used in JavaSE?

Comment: To just display the GPS Location from DB to Desktop users, why do you need Location manager, etc

Comment: True. I dont need it. Thx